# Splitting monolith into microservices

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, microservices

I have an existing web service that supports ordering and it has multiple operations (approximately 20). This is a single webservice that support the ordering function. It interacts with multiple other services to provide ordering capability.

Since there is a lot of business functionality within this app and it is supported by a 10 member team , I believe it is a monolith (though I assume there is no hard and fast rule to define what a monolith is).

We are planning to get the application deployed in cloud foundry environment and we are planning to split the app into 2-3 microservices , primarily to enable them scale independently.

The first few apis which enable searching for a product typically have more number of hits whereas the api that support actual order submission receives less that 5% of the hits. So the product search api should have significantly larger number of instances as compared to order submission api.

Though I am not sure if we could split is based on sub-domains (which I have read should be the basis) , we are thinking of splitting them based on the call sequence as explained earlier.

I have also read that microservices should be choreographed and not orchestrated. However in order to ensure our existing consumers are not impacted , I believe we should expose a api layer which would orchestrate the calls to these microservices. Is providing an api gateway , the normal approach that is followed to ensure consumers do not end up calling multiple microservices and also provides a layer of abstraction?

This seems to be orchestration more than choreography - though I am not hung up on the theoretical aspects , I would like to understand the different solutions that are pursued for this problem statement in an enterprise world.

Comment: Do not split for search and update/create! Api usage differences is not a good reason to split.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The Benefits of Microservices

- Deploy & Scale Independently
- Easier to 'Reason About'
- Separation of Concerns
- Single Responsibility
- (Micro)Service-Oriented Architecture

I would suggest splitting your services based on domain.  This is a logical and efficient approach which makes it an easy starting point.  Your monolithic package structure may already be organized in this manner, which simplifies the refactoring even more.

### API Gateway

The typical Spring Cloud approach for this would be to use a Zuul Proxy on the edge of your network which receives the requests from your clients (web, mobile, etc.) and routes them to the microservices located behind your firewall.  The client only interfaces with a single domain, and it handles CORS out of the box.

Resources:

- [API Gateway Pattern](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_the_api_gateway_pattern_angular_js_and_spring_security_part_iv)
- [Routing and Filtering](http://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/)

Comment: Thanks @punkrocker27ka! If I have 3 micro services exposing 6 different end points , would Zuul proxy layer expose all the 6 endpoints to the consuming application & route the requests to appropriate micro services ? Does Zuul proxy layer provide caching , policy management ( call sequence of APIs) & transformation ( some existing consumers want xml support while new customers want rest support ) capabilities ?

Comment: A Proxy simply proxies the request to the microservice. How your microservice processes the reqeuest is up to you. For the XML and "rest" support. I guess you mean XML or JSON. This depends on the "Accept"-Header of the request and should be handled in your microservice and not by zuul.
An API Gateway is used to hide the architecture in the background so you are able to extract logic step by step to microservices.

Comment: @PunterVicky The Zuul proxy typically works by pattern matching URLs.  So for example, the web browser client makes an HTTP call to endpoint /api/resource1/customers and also to /api/resource2/suppliers  You will write routing rules based on the URL.  /api/resource1/** = 10.0.0.101  and /api/resource2/** = 10.0.0.102  This is a simple example but you get the picture.  Zuul will route the requests based on the configuration you implement.  The web browser client doesn't know anything about the separate services which is good for them, but you can split and organize your services anyway you like

Comment: @PunterVicky Caching is outside the scope of Zuul but can easily be implemented in tandem.  To route requests based on XML or JSON you can specify that in the URL or in the HttpRequest and write a rule that handles that.  Check the docs for the nitty gritty details.